# How to find GPS info from a geotagged photo?

Tags: photos, gps

I photo many details for job with my smartphone and I have turn on the geotag option.

Those info are in the jpg file? If so how can I extract them?

Comment: View & Extract them on phone ? On computer ? What OS ?

Comment: Check [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/how-to-find-out-whether-a-photo-is-geotagged-or-not) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you took the photos without geo-tagging turned on, there's no way for you to get the information you need from those photographs.

However, if geo-tagging was turned on at the time you took the photos, you can read the info like so:

### Windows

- Right click on the photo, choose **Properties** (alternatively, select the file and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Switch to the **Details** tab and you should see the GPS co-ordinates on that pane, under the **GPS** section.
  [image: GPS co-ordinates windows]

  <sup>Image credit: [makeuseof.com](http://makeuseof.com)</sup>
- Alternatively, you could use [ExifDataView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/exif_data_view.html) to read this information.

### Mac OS / *nix

- Download and [install ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html).
- Run `exiftool <image.jpg> | grep GPS`